# Doesn't add meta tags - Vue and declandewet/Vue-meta

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vue-meta

Hi everyone and thanks for your help.

This project use Vue-CLI, Vue-Router and Vue-meta.
I want to update meta tags description and keywords.
Currently, the meta title is correctly updated, but I can't update description and keywords.

```
//App.vue
    metaInfo: {
        title: 'App',
        titleTemplate: '%s | My Awesome Webapp',
        meta: [
            {vmid: 'description', property: 'description', content: 'meta1'},
            {vmid: 'keywords', property: 'keywords', content: 'keys1'}
        ]
    }

//home.vue
      name: 'home',
        metaInfo: {
            // title: 'My Page Title',
            // titleTemplate: '%s',
            meta: [
                {vmid: 'description', property: 'description', content: 'meta2'},
                {vmid: 'keywords', property: 'keywords', content: 'keys2'}
            ]
        }

    //index.html
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="keywords" content="">
</head>
```

Thanks for your help,

Comment: do you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try calling using the `metaInfo` field as a function

```
metaInfo: () => ({
  meta: [{ name: 'description', content: 'Hello', vmid: 'test' }],
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Indrek Lasn. 
Unfortunately, it didn't work.